# Open zsh scripts in sh-mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, zsh

`*.zsh` files open in the default mode (text-mode for me). However, sh-mode is actually multiple modes including behaviours for zsh, bash, etc. How can I tell emacs to open `*.zsh` files specifically in the zsh flavor of sh-mode?

Comment: Add an entry to `auto-mode-alist` mapping the `.zsh` suffix to the mode you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The flavor of sh-mode is autodetected from the shebang line (first line of your script).  If you have "#!/bin/zsh", zsh will be assumed and (for instance) `autoload` will be recognized as a keyword.  `autoload` will be not recognized as such if first line is "#!/bin/bash"

To make emacs recognize *.zsh files as shell scripts, just add this to your init file:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.zsh\\'" . sh-mode))
```

A programmatic way of selecting a flavor when you don't want to use the shebang is doing this in a sh-mode buffer:

```
(sh-set-shell "zsh")
```

So in your case what you need (unless you use shebang) is to update the auto-mode-alist as above and

```
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (string-match "\\.zsh$" buffer-file-name)
                (sh-set-shell "zsh"))))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I knew about calling sh-mode but not that it autodetected the type. What if I don't have a sebang line, can I still make it work automatically?

Comment: Do you have an idea why `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.zsh\\'" . sh-mode))` has absolutely no effect in my emacs? `sh-mode` is installed, I can launch it manually no problem.

Answer (score 9):

Whether your file has a `#!` shebang or not, you can always use a file mode line or a local variables section to set shell-script mode.  Having one of these in your script will allow Emacs to do the right thing even if you haven't updated the auto-mode-alist, so is recommended for any non-standard file extension.

The Emacs file mode line for shell scripts is `-*- mode: sh -*-`. It should be in a comment, and must appear on the first line (or the second line if the first one is a shebang line).

If you can't put it on the first (second) line for some reason, you can create a local variables section at the end of the file (in the last 3000 characters of the file, and on the last page, [according to the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html)):

```
# Local Variables:
# mode: sh
# End:
```

Note that just setting the Emacs mode will still rely on a shebang line for shell type autodetection, and if no shebang line is detected will default to the current `SHELL` environment variable or the value of `sh-shell-file` if set).

If you can't have a shebang line, but want the correct shell type to be selected, the only way to do this is with an `eval` in the mode line or local variables section.  Adding this will generate a confirmation prompt every time the file is loaded into Emacs, so this is not generally recommended, but may be acceptable in some cases.
The mode line would be `-*- mode: sh; eval: (sh-set-shell "zsh") -*-`, and the local variables form would be:

```
# Local Variables:
# mode: sh
# eval: (sh-set-shell "zsh")
# End:
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very cool! I'm scheming awesome ways to use this feature now.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the shebang method, a more robust form is

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# env will search the path for zsh.  Some distros may put it a different place.
# env is pretty much guaranteed to be in /usr/bin
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question.